# Why does Ubuntu install ARM64 compilers with a version suffix that breaks autoconf?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cross-compiling, autoconf, arm64

I just installed the ARM64 cross-complier (aarch64-linux-gnu) on x86_64 Ubuntu 16.04 and all of the binaries have "-4.8" (like aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc-4.8). When I try to configure with `--host=aarch64-linux-gnu`, it fails to find `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc` and falls back to the native `gcc`.

What did I miss? Is there an additional package that needs installation other than `gcc-4.8-aarch64-linux-gnu`? Or is there another mystery parameter to autogen.sh/configure that I don't know about?

Thanks.

Comment: would it be worthwhile moving this to https://unix.stackexchange.com/?